# How to run a services as some user(other than root) using YAJSW?

Tags: yajsw

I have a services running as root user, How to run this services as some user(other than root) using YAJSW on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/YAJSW%20Configuration%20Parameters.html

```
wrapper.app.account=some-user
```